# Conditional transpose using SAS

Tags: sas, transpose, lag

I have a dataset that looks like the following for multiple patients. I am trying to subtract each visit value from the baseline value of corresponding variables (which are sometimes missing).

```
Data Have: 
Patient Variable Value  Visit 
A       Height    100   Baseline
A       Weight     50   Baseline
A       HDCIRC     30   Baseline
A       BMI        50   Baseline
A       Height    100   a
A       Weight     50   a
A       HDCIRC     30   a
A       BMI        50   a
A       Height    100   b
A       Weight     50   b

Data Want: 
Patient Variable Value  Visit     BASELINE  Change 
A       Height    100   Baseline   100       0
A       Weight     50   Baseline   50        0
A       HDCIRC     30   Baseline   30        0
A       BMI        50   Baseline   50        0
A       Height    120   a          100       20
A       Weight     50   a          50        0
A       HDCIRC     30   a          30        0
A       BMI        34.7 a          50        -15.3
A       Height    150   b          100       50
A       Weight     51   b          50        1
```

My attempt would be to first create BASELINE and then calculate the change. 
In order to get BASELINE, I've seen some people use a lag or a dif function. How can I correctly create the BASELINE variable?

```
proc sort data=have;
by patient visit;
;

data want;
set have;
by patient visit;
difstamp = dif(visit);
if first.patient then do;
  dif=0;
end;
else dif=difstamp;
drop difstamp;
run;

proc sort data=want;
by timestamp;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative you could simply merge have with itself

```
data have;
input Patient $ Variable $ Value Visit $;
cards;
A       Height    100   Baseline
A       Weight     50   Baseline
A       HDCIRC     30   Baseline
A       BMI        50   Baseline
A       Height    120   a
A       Weight     50   a
A       HDCIRC     30   a
A       BMI        34.7 a
A       Height    150   b
A       Weight     51   b
;

proc sort;
 by patient variable;
run;
data want;
  merge have have(where=(__visit='Baseline') keep=patient variable value visit rename=(visit=__visit value=BASELINE))
  ;
  by patient variable;
  Change=Value-BASELINE;
  drop __:;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably helps to sort by PATIENT VARIABLE so that you can get the baseline.
If your VISIT variable doesn't properly sort BASELINE to the first visit then you can use WHERE= dataset options to make sure the baseline appear first.

```
data have;
input Patient $ Variable $ Value Visit $;
cards;
A       Height    100   Baseline
A       Weight     50   Baseline
A       HDCIRC     30   Baseline
A       BMI        50   Baseline
A       Height    120   a
A       Weight     50   a
A       HDCIRC     30   a
A       BMI        34.7 a
A       Height    150   b
A       Weight     51   b
;

proc sort;
 by patient variable visit;
run;
data want;
  set have(in=in1 where=(visit='Baseline'))
      have(in=in2 where=(visit^='Baseline'))
  ;
  by patient variable ;
  if first.variable then do;
    if in1 then baseline=Value;
    else baseline=.;
    retain baseline;
  end;
  if n(value,baseline)=2 then change=value-baseline;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    PATIENT    VARIABLE    VALUE    VISIT       BASELINE    CHANGE

   1       A        BMI         50.0    Baseline        50         0.0
   2       A        BMI         34.7    a               50       -15.3
   3       A        HDCIRC      30.0    Baseline        30         0.0
   4       A        HDCIRC      30.0    a               30         0.0
   5       A        Height     100.0    Baseline       100         0.0
   6       A        Height     120.0    a              100        20.0
   7       A        Height     150.0    b              100        50.0
   8       A        Weight      50.0    Baseline        50         0.0
   9       A        Weight      50.0    a               50         0.0
  10       A        Weight      51.0    b               50         1.0
```